# File view freezes blender 2.8

Tags: file-browser

Every time I try to do anything with blender file view it takes a really long time to open it and it usually gives me a not responding situation . This happens for anything file view related : importing , exporting and any kind of saving ( from file to image ) . This is really tiresome because it happens only at work on most of the pc's here that use blender .

I have an intel core i7-7700k CPU , 4.20 GHz , 16 GB RAM and  GeForce GTX 1050 .

Comment: Do you happen to have network drives in your bookmarks or most recent directories?